# Magento Quanty Boxes in Category Product List (Add more then one artikle) (No Grouped or Bundle options please)

Tags: php, magento

here´s flo from Germany.

I´ve searched the whole Internert for any solution but no way.

I´would like to make it possible to give a quanty box at the grid view product category list!

I´ve used the following code in list.phtml:

```
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>       
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>:</label><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo ($this->getMinimalQty($_product)?$this->getMinimalQty($_product):1) ?>" class="qty inputstyled" style="margin: 4px 10px 4px 5px;" />
     <?php endif; ?>
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></span></button>
</form>
```

This works great, but I would like to use this one with:
One add to cart click >>  Add more artikels in diverent quantys to cart.
For example I will add with only on add-to-cart button click this following all things
7 T-Shirts in blue, 4 T-Shirts in yellow and 2 T-Shirts in green

Which changes should I have to do, to get this running??

Could any one help me! I´m  using Magento 1.8.1 CE

I know everything about bundle and grouped artikles and I will not have any anthwer: So I should use this! Then I will use it with category product list and not with grouped artikles! Same feature but other solution.

Many Thanks for solutions,
Best Regards from Germany!

Answer (score 0):

There's work around for your need. Since you already customized the template, you are one step ahead. Please read carefully below and do (I am gonna be short to answer)

1. Modify list.phtml to wrap all product qty box in single form (I think you are wrapping a product in a form now). That means you should place your code before foreach($_productCollection ....) line , around line no 47 and close the form after this loop ends (below endforeach), around line no 80. You also place a hidden input where you cam send product_it (entity_id) on form post. Make sure it can send product_id and qty in array (field name should be like product_id[], notice [])
2. Extend and customize Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction (app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controller/CartController). Modify function in such way so that when data comes in array (like in list.phtml), it adds product in cart in loop. There lot of info on how to extend controller -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller, http://inchoo.net/tools-frameworks/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/

Hope u follow and this will fix ur problem.
Thanks